# return biggest value from query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

i want to find which employee has the most orders:  this code brings all the orders count from all the users:

```
    public void GetBestEmployeeFromDates(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
        {
            var query =
                from z in db.Employees
                select new
                {
                    OrderNumber = z.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderDate > fromDate.Date).Count()
                };

        }

    }
```

how should i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `MaxBy` (http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/):

```
var maxOrders = query.MaxBy(o => o.OrderNumbers);
```

You could also adjust your query to include the customer name:

```
var query =
            from z in db.Employees
            select new
            {   
                Customer = z.CustomerName,
                OrderNumber = z.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderDate > fromDate.Date).Count()
            };

var person = query.OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderNumber).Select(c=>c.Customer).First();

Console.WriteLine("The customer with the most orders is: " + person);
```

Comment: its good but, i am getting the number that way... i want the name :)

Comment: @darko: You are referring to `Max` and not `MaxBy`.

Comment: The query is Not Linq to objects.

Comment: i dont see that prop "MaxBy"... why?

Comment: @darko - mrobably because you don't have the morelinq extensions.  I have updated my answer to just use an order by clause.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking something like this:

```
using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
{
 var query =
   (from z in db.Employees
   select new
   {
      OrderNumber = z.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderDate > fromDate.Date).Count(),
      Employee = z
   }).OrderByDescending(x => OrderNumber).Select(x => x.Employee).FirstOrDefault()
}
```